# Array to List converting and type casting

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, list, type-conversion

**Motive:**

Im creating an android Application that does the following.

1. Reads input points (of type Point - a custom class).
2. Calculates the outermost points.
3. Draws a polygon (needs input of type GeoPoint from osmdroid library) with those points as the vertices (a convex polygon).

**Problem:**

I made the algorithm to work. But there is a problem converting the datatypes.

The input is a Point array(Point is a custom class).

```
geoPoints = new Point[7];
geoPoints[0] = new Point(new GeoPoint(8.180992, 77.336551));
```

But the osmdroid function that draws the polygon needs List < GeoPoint > as input.

```
List<GeoPoint> gPoints;
polygon.setPoints(gPoints);
```

I managed to convert this on the Point() constructor like something below

```
public Point(GeoPoint geoPoint) {
        this.x = geoPoint.getLatitude();
        this.y = geoPoint.getLongitude();
    }
```

But I have no idea how work out the return type.

SO, when I run the code. I get the following error.

```
error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
equality constraints: GeoPoint
lower bounds: Point
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in method <T>asList(T...)
```

**Calling Function:**

```
private void callingFunction() {

        geoPoints = new Point[7];
        geoPoints[0] = new Point(new GeoPoint(8.180992, 77.336551));
        geoPoints[1] = new Point(new GeoPoint(8.183966, 77.340353));
        geoPoints[2] = new Point(new GeoPoint(8.179836, 77.336105));
        geoPoints[3] = new Point(new GeoPoint(8.178744, 77.339179));
        geoPoints[4] = new Point(new GeoPoint(8.182155, 77.341925));
        geoPoints[5] = new Point(new GeoPoint(8.181655, 77.339318));
        geoPoints[6] = new Point(new GeoPoint(8.182155, 77.341925));

        polygon = new Polygon();    //see note below
        polygon.setFillColor(Color.parseColor("#80FFE082"));
        polygon.setStrokeColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD54F"));
        polygon.setStrokeWidth(5f);

        ConvexHull cx = new ConvexHull(geoPoints);
        Point C1[]= cx.getConvexHull();

        polygon.setPoints(Arrays.asList(C1));

        map.getOverlayManager().add(polygon);
        map.invalidate();

    }
```

**Note:**

Using only List or only Array is not possible as

```
polygon.setPoints(geoPoints)    //needs List<GeoPoint> in callingFunction
Arrays.sort(points);            //requires array of Points in ConvexHull
```

Everything provided. How can I solve this problem? Any sorts of help will be really useful. And Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you change your Point class to extend GeoPoint? Then you could just pass the List.

Comment: Not really - sorry! Did you read the page about [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's not so much about just reducing the amount of code you post but rather about creating the smallest possible example you can - probably in a whole new project - that boils it down to the specific problem and nothing else. It's also a good idea to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - note in particular "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague" - nobody has time to read all that much code when they're offering their help for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I got you right, but basically your problem boils down to the fact, that you have an array of `Point` objects, but need a list of `GeoPoint` objects instead, right? And there is no relation between `Point` and `GeoPoint`, so one does not extend the other.

So why not translate `Point` objects back to `GeoPoint` objects before drawing the polygon?

You could map types in a stream:

```
ConvexHull cx = new ConvexHull(geoPoints);
Point C1[] = cx.getConvexHull();

polygon.setPoints(Arrays.stream(C1).map(p -> new GeoPoint(p.getX(), p.getY())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or use a `for` loop:

```
ConvexHull cx = new ConvexHull(geoPoints);
Point C1[] = cx.getConvexHull();

List<GeoPoint> points = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>(C1.length);
for (int i = 0; i < C1.length; ++i) {
  points.add(new GeoPoint(C1[i].getX(), C1[i].getY()));
}
polygon.setPoints(points);
```

Comment: The call requires API 24. My curent min is 16. I cant change the min from 16 as we are targetting devices running older versions of android. Is there any workaround ?

Comment: Use a ``for`` loop to transform the ``Point`` array to a list of ``GeoPoint`` objects.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added a ``for`` loop alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your super fast reply. Your code actually solved my issue. Have been working this for 2 day now. And im marking this as the accepted answer. Thanks a lot. Off topic but, is there any way there is a desktop app for S.O. im getting the notifications a little late.